# Android glsurfaceview, should collision testing and "ai movement" calculations be performed using asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, glsurfaceview

I remember reading, in regards to a standard canvas based surfaceview, that one would want to use asynctask to offload major operations from the main thread (for instance NPC movement and attached collision)

I could see this working well, with the asynctask sending the results when it has them, and the NPCs only moving when these results are in and an update has been made to their locations...

Is this necessary/recommended with GLSurfaceView? I'm asking because I just read that some sort of "trick" is involved in achieving this, which leads me to believe it may not be the best course of action...

Thanks!

Comment: I did it on the render thread in Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/), but the calculations are pretty quick.  If state updates are more complex, separating the game state into a dedicated thread may make more sense (see e.g. Replica Island, https://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out no "trick" of any sort is required...

Just the by the book implementation of the asynctask inner class. I put it directly in my "class name" extends GLSurfaceView class.

On another note, performance difference is negligible... Might just make life more difficult for missile collision. MORE TESTING REQUIRED :)